How does Android back i.e allowBackup, dataExtractionRules affect libraries?
I am just curious, how do the various data backup thing affect SDKs in Android?
For example, I am working on an SDK that will be implemented into several Android projects.
For this SDK, we download configs from a backend service, and I have noticed at least on Samsung devices, when allowBackup=true, the old config is retrieved rather than the new one. When we use allowBackup=false it seems to work.
I know this may be deprecated in the future so there are some others:
allowBackup
dataExtractionRules
fullBackupContent
I want to ensure that our SDK doesn't backup anything so it always gets newest data. I am curious however, if we set everything to false and to not backup anything, but the app that integrates our SDK has allowBackup=true or something else, will it override ours and start backup things up?
Also our data_extraction_rules looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data-extraction-rules>
    <cloud-backup>
        <exclude domain="root" />
        <exclude domain="file" />
        <exclude domain="database" />
        <exclude domain="sharedpref" />
        <exclude domain="external" />
    </cloud-backup>
    <device-transfer>
        <exclude domain="root" />
        <exclude domain="file" />
        <exclude domain="database" />
        <exclude domain="sharedpref" />
        <exclude domain="external" />
    </device-transfer>
</data-extraction-rules>

Does it look ok to not backup anything?
